# Datatable issues when presenting dynamic columns

Tags: primefaces

I've got a NULLPointerException. 
I have iplemented an object called Workhours, which has list of Hours and a workday (enum value).
Now, I have a list 
I would like to present it in a datatable with the workday (enum) name as a row, and the hours as columns. Now, this is what I tried:

```
                <p:dataTable id="dtWorkHours" var="workhour" value="#{uploadImagesPage.lwh}"  >
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Days"></h:outputText>                               
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{workhour.workday}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:columns value="#{workhour.luh}" var="columnUntilHours" columnIndexVar="index">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                             #{columnUntilHours.untilhours}
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{columnUntilHours.checked}" >
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </p:columns>
                </p:dataTable>
```

I checked initialization of WorkHours object and it seems everythings's in place. Is there any reason why I p:columns doesn't work (and when I put it out, the workday presentation as row works)?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to mix dynamic and static columns within a single Primefaces dataTable.  You must choose one method or the other.

If you wish to show the `workday` column within this then perhaps you can create create a viewable composite entity type that combines properties of both workday and the row entities into a single type.  Workday can be just another object that always exist in your dynamic column collection.

Comment: I was required to make some modifications to my entities to supply the datatable with the correct dynamic columns. It seems to me odd that I have to modify my DB entities according to the GUI... Oh, well, when it works, don't mess with it...

Comment: @lionheart, I am glad that worked for you.  This isn't terribly uncommon in any framework where binding entities directly to UI components.  In my design I typically create my normal Persistence/ORM entities and bind these directly to simple UI components, then I also have View entities/Composite Entities that wrap one or more of my base entities to have custom display and control over columns.  I have had similar designs in applications written for WinForms, ASP.NET and JSF2.